# JQuery Confirm not directing to link before any input is provided

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, confirm

I've seen lots of people ask for help with JQuery confirmation messages, however I am using the JQuery Confirm plugin link: https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/
My problem is that when the modal opens, it closes right away without the user being able to click anything. Not only does it close, but it just goes to the specified href link. How can I get it to wait for the user. I'm using MVC Visual C# with Razor.

This is my javascript for the confirmation box.

```
$('.deleteAdmin').on('click', function () {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Delete Admin',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to delete this admin?',
        confirmButton: 'Yes',
        cancelButton: 'Cancel',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn-success',
        animation: 'rotate',
        animationBounce: 1.3,
        theme: 'black',
        animationSpeed: 800
    });
});
```

The only way I have been able to keep the confirmation box to stay on the page is to have either in the `<a>` link `onclick="return false;"`, or have `return false;` in the on click function, however, both make it so nothing happens ever.

The section of my cshtml file is

```
<td class="admin-table-delete-style"><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteAdmin","Stats",new { adminToRemove = @item.UserName })" class="deleteAdmin">Delete</a></td>
```

Where item.UserName is the username of the admin to delete (that part works fine).

The creator's website uses this exact code for theirs and it works

```
$('.example2').on('click', function () {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Simple confirm!',
        confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        }
    });
});
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: because the jquery confirm can not pause the execution of the code so the code that you clicked on still runs.

Comment: @epascarello then why make the plugin? it works perfectly fine in their examples on their page, when I do the same thing, how come it doesn't work on mine?

Comment: because you need to handle the action after the select something. You need to cancel the click, than do the confirm, and when they select okay, you call the JavaScript code.

Comment: All the confirmation thing does is make it so if you click no, you don't go to the link, if you confirm it, then it goes.

Comment: Yes, but since there is no way to pause you need to cancel the default action and fire it yourself. It is impossible to write your own window.confirm, prompt, alert and pause execution of script.

Comment: @epascarello The creator uses the code I updated the post with, and theirs works fine. There is also the simplified version of just `$('blahhere').on('click', function () {
$.confirm('stuff','title'); });`

Comment: Inside the confirm callback where they have an alert you would need to call the code the link is calling.

Comment: I suppose I should have used the `<a>` link example, but they do exactly what I'm tring to do with an anchor link and it works.
`<a class="example2-1-1 btn btn-primary" data-title="Goto twitter?" href="http://twitter.com/craftpip">Goto twitter</a>`


`$('.example2-1-1').confirm({
    content: "This will take you to my twitter",
});`

Comment: Well you are not using it the same way their confirm example works on a link....

Comment: Even if I use it the exact same way....

Comment: So you did `$('#deleteAdmin').confirm({/*options*/});`?

Comment: the *options* are all the things you can choose to add such as title, content, animations, speed, etc, but yes, I've even tried the simplest one

Answer (score 1):

The native JavaScript *alert* function is **blocking** where the jQuery one is **non-blocking**. This is the reason why the jQuery *$.confirm* function provides you callback functions for *confirm* and *cancel*.

Comment: but you don't have to use the callback functions, it is supposed to work without all that

Comment: No, but if you do not use them, you won't be able to retrieve the user decision (confirm or cancel). It would just hide the element from your window's body.